# Rename and overwrite files using wildcard in Windows

Tags: powershell, batch-file, rename, wildcard

I am working on a script for auto deployment, where I need to replace my files with the same filenames.

For example, I have the following files in my current directory

```
deployment.properties
wrapper.conf
config.properties
```

Later, I will generate another set of files like this

```
deployment.properties.tokenized
wrapper.conf.tokenized
config.properties.tokenized
```

Lastly, I want to replace the existing config files (in the first code block) using the *.tokenized version and remove the tokenized files.

In Linux, the following can do the job. But I don't know how to do in Windows

```
for f in *tokenized; 
  do mv "$f" "`echo $f | sed s/tokenized//`";
done
```

I tried to use powershell's move-item, rename-item but still cannot figure out the right way to do it. Could somebody help? bat / powershell scripts are both welcomed. Using loop is also okay. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost the same code but in `cmd / batch files` we have access to the elements of the file name.

From command line

```
for %a in (*.tokenized) do move /y "%a" "%~na"
```

Or, for a batch file (you need to escape the `for` replaceable parameter)

```
for %%a in (*.tokenized) do move /y "%%a" "%%~na"
```

As the extension of the file (the text after the last dot) is `.tokenized`, when you request just the name (without extension) of the file being referenced (`%%~na`) you get the original file name.

Answer (score 1):

This PowerShell script should do the job:

```
Get-ChildItem *.tokenized | % {
    move $_.Name ([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Name)) -Force
}
```

Comment: Sorry. To be exact, I may want to move the file from "myfile.to.be.tokenized" to "myfile". If it only drops the extension, would it be "myfile.to.be"?

Comment: Yes, this will drop only last part.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, I can run it multiple times until all extensions are gone.